# Suboptimal execution plan is better than optimal plan when statistics are stale

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

Why the cost of the execution plan that was generated based on stale statistics is cheaper than the cost of the plan based on updated statistics?

To understand my problem please to follow below scenario:

Assumption: auto statistics update is off.

When I updated statistics with full scan manually then I executed following batch including actual execution plan:

```
CHECKPOINT;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;

SELECT *
FROM AWSales -- table has 60000 rows
WHERE SalesOrderID = 44133
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
--returns 17 rows
```

The optimizer generated a plan that used non clustered index seek and key lookup - that was definitely fine.

Then I wanted to cheat the optimizer so I inserted 60 000 rows where input value for SalesOrderID column was 44133.

Without updating statistics I executed the mentioned batch again and the optimizer returned the same plan (with index seek) but with different cost (60 000 rows returned), of course.

Next I updated statistics with full scan manually for the table and I executed the batch again. This time the optimizer returned different plan with index scan operator. Predictable. At first glance it looked good. But when I compared the query plan costs it was more expensive than the cost of plan that used index seek. So after updating statistics query with optimal plan was slower. NONSENSE!
Then I wanted to compare costs of index seek before update and after update. Updated statistics caused the optimizer chose plan with index scan, so to force generating plan with index seek I added hint into the query. After executing it turned out that the actual query cost (forced index scan) was MUCH bigger then cost when statistics were stale. How is that possible?

For more details please look at sample [script](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZU1lZXdsVWM2cWc)

Comment: Given that SalesOrderID is not a PK  and that you have a select * “star” – all fields I would expect the plans you are describing.  The really high cost in execution 4 could be just from the *.  Try making execution 4b something like SELECT SalesOrderID FROM AWSales  WITH (INDEX(ixOrders)) WHERE SalesOrderID = 44133  OPTION(RECOMPILE);